# Office communicator option

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I am looking or icon/option for office communicator 
Embed in office power point 2010, when click icon running presentation, it should be open direct video chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just embed a link to the sip address you want to start a conversation with:

```
sip:someone@domain.com
```

Comment: thanks for valuable responce partailly work but did not got actaul option, will you please provide further support

Comment: what would be sip for calling (sip:someone@domain.com?call)